# Bash script not appending

Tags: bash

I want to build a list of words with the following bash script but append is not working:

```
declare -a NODES=()
cat $1 | while read line;do
    for word in $line; do
       NODES+=("$word")
       echo $word
    done
done

echo "Nodes: ${NODES[@]}"
```

I get the output:

```
 node01
 node02
 node03
 node04
 Nodes:
```

To run the script:

```
 $ bash myscript.sh nodes_list
```

nodes_list file:
     node01
     node02
     node03
     node04

Comment: Whats your input. Also it doesn't work because you are assigning values in a subshell, i'd find a duplicate but i honestly can't be bothered. Use  `while read blah;do blah;done < file`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've been caught out by a classic issue relating to pipes - each side of the pipe is executed in its own subshell, so the array you're using goes out of scope and its contents vanish after the loop.

Your problem can be solved simply (and you get rid of a useless use of `cat` too):

```
nodes=() # no need to use declare here, use lowercase variable names
while read -r line; do # -r switch is almost always what you want
    for word in $line; do
       nodes+=("$word")
       echo "$word" # always quote your variables!
    done
done < "$1" # use redirection instead of a pipe to avoid creating a subshell

echo "Nodes: ${nodes[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Tom Fenech is good, given your use case and problem, however you can also create an array using IFS:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare nodes=( $(<"$1") )

for (( i = 0; i < ${#nodes[@]}; ++i )); do
  echo "line: ${i}: ${nodes[$i]}"
done
```

Saving that previous code as `toto.bash`, it will echo that:

```
$ ./toto.bash toto.bash
line: 0: #!/bin/bash
line: 1: declare
line: 2: nodes=(
line: 3: $(<"$1")
line: 4: )
line: 5: for
line: 6: ((
line: 7: i
line: 8: =
line: 9: 0;
line: 10: i
line: 11: <
line: 12: ${#nodes[@]};
line: 13: ++i
line: 14: ));
line: 15: do
line: 16: echo
line: 17: "line:
line: 18: ${i}:
line: 19: ${nodes[$i]}"
line: 20: done
```

If you need to split by line (eg: get an array containing each line), you can do that:

```
OIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
declare nodes=( $(<"$1") )
IFS=$OIFS
```

The OIFS is here to restore the previous IFS, to avoid unwanted side effect.